# pthread_cancel not cancelling all the threads

Tags: pthreads, mutex

I have 4 threads which all execute the same `while` loop . After a certain amount of time one of the threads reaches the *threshold point* and stops execution.

The 3 remaining threads are not getting canceled. I believe the `Threshold` global variable is visible to all 4 threads. How can I make sure that all the threads suspend execution at the `Threshold` point?

---

I have set the following attributes for the threads:

1. Same lock and unlock `MUTEX` for all 4 threads
2. Set pthreads cancel type to `ENABLED`

Comment: Why don't you post a stripped-down, minimal version of your code that compiles and runs?

Comment: @JanezKuhar . Thank you . I was able to solve this last night by using Pointers